# Output ogg / FLAC from Adobe Audition

Tags: format, export, adobe-audition

How can I export an ogg or FLAC file from adobe Audition? is there a plugin? If so, how do I install it, both on Mac and Windows? preferably looking for an all in one solution for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Audition myself in years so I don't know if there is any plugin to do this, but even if there isn't, the classic workflow is to export to .wav or .aiff, and then use the converter of your choice to convert that to Ogg Vorbis or FLAC.

This will work for any tool that records audio, not just Audition.

Comment: On a personal note [OGG](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402659.html) seems to be possible. But I'd recommend following Warrior Bob's suggestion: Export it as wav or aiff and then convert.

Comment: yeah...but I realy am trying to find a good and easy way to export directly (reduce steps in production chain. and audacity is actualy a step backwards for what I am trying to accomplish. plus I dont have a "converter of [my] choice for ogg flac (on a mac) and audacity is cumbersome because I want to work in bulk as much as posible. I realy dont want to have to open multiple programs if I dont have to. I am working on setting up a workflow for a volunteer to use

Comment: @mjrider Fair enough! Might want to edit your question though, so that it's clear you're looking for an all-in-one solution. For what it's worth, I [XLD](http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html) does convert to FLAC on OSX, and can do so in batches.